# Ingress backend REST error: The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request. Please try again in 30 seconds

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am deploying application at Google kubernetes engine. Application has 2 services. There is also `Ingress` which I am trying to use to expose one service and `ingress` also used for https support. I have 1 `NodePort` service "gateway" and `ClusterIp` service "internal". "Internal" should be accessed from gateway. Here is services config:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: x-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: x-x-ip
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
  labels:
    app: gateway
spec:
  tls:
    - secretName: secret
      hosts:
      - x.x.com
  backend:
    serviceName: gateway
    servicePort: 80
---
apiVersion: certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: x-x
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: x@x.com
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: x-x
    http01: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.alpha.kubernetes.io/tolerate-unready-endpoints: "true"
  name: gateway
  labels:
    app: gateway
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    name: gateway
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: gateway
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.alpha.kubernetes.io/tolerate-unready-endpoints: "true"
  name: internal
  labels:
    app: internal
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8082
    name: internal
    targetPort: 8082
  selector:
    app: internal
```

Gateway serve static content and REST resources. Static content is served ok, so I see html and images and scripts. But when i try to call REST endpoint I got `The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request. Please try again in 30 seconds.` Gateway forward REST request to "internal" service and return response from internal. Gateway access internal service with URL `http://internal:8082/some/rest`. I got errors when I call any request which should be forwarded to "internal".

Actually I have same scheme without `Ingress` and it works. "Gateway" is `LoadBalancer` service and "internal" is `NodePort`. I need `Ingress` for https.

UPD: I noticed I don't have any forwarding rules related to `8082` port, only `80` and `443`( I have used `gcloud compute forwarding-rules list` and `gcloud compute forwarding-rules describe` commands).

Here is output of `kubectl describe svc`

```
Name:                     gateway
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app=gateway
Annotations:              service.alpha.kubernetes.io/tolerate-unready-endpoints=true
Selector:                 app=gateway
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       *
Port:                     gateway  80/TCP
TargetPort:               8080/TCP
NodePort:                 gateway  31168/TCP
Endpoints:                *:8080
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
---
Name:              internal
Namespace:         default
Labels:            app=internal
Annotations:       service.alpha.kubernetes.io/tolerate-unready-endpoints=true
Selector:          app=internal
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                *
Port:              internal  8082/TCP
TargetPort:        8082/TCP
Endpoints:         *:8082
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

UPD2: Here is output of `curl -v` to problem URL:

```
*   Trying *.*.*.*...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to *.*.*.* port 80 (#0)
> GET /internal/ping HTTP/1.1
> Host: *
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
< Content-Length: 332
< Date: Sun, 04 Mar 2018 05:19:59 GMT
< 
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>502 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Server Error</h1>
<h2>The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host trial.qurasense.com left intact
```

When this URL requested, nothing happens in gateway logs.

Comment: Did you deploy all pods/replicasets/deployments in the same namespace? Does the service ˋinternalˋ have a healthy endpoint entry when you ˋdescribe svcˋ? What port are you trying to connect to on the ˋinternalˋ service? Cluster internal access should not be affected by a nodeport or ingress...

Comment: Hi @AndreasJägle, they have `default` namespace. I din't found healthy endpoint for internal serivce in describe output. I use 8082 port to connect. I switched to Ingress from LoadBalncer - there i had all services NodePort type(both gateway and internal was NodePort), and didn't had such problems.

Comment: There isn't enough information to answer the question. How does app gateway access service internal? What is the REST call being issued against?

Comment: Hi @JonahBenton you are right, i will update question.

Comment: @JonahBenton Gateway forward REST request to "internal" service and return response from internal. Gateway access internal service with url http://internal:8082/some/rest. I got errors when i call any request wich should be forwarded to "internal".

Comment: What does curl -v to the gateway url that forwards to internal say, and what do the logs of the gateway application say when this occurs?

Comment: @JonahBenton i updated question, added this information to bottom.

Comment: With the provided information I just can say ingress is correctly defined and it forward the requests to the pods targeted with service "gateway".

Now, it is not clear how are these pods forwarding the requests to the pods targeted with service "internal". Also, does the path /some/rest exist and it returns 200 from within the server (localhost:8020/some/rest)?

Comment: Hi @suren, thanks for comment. Yes it returns 200, when i launch internal service at localhost. About forwarding - i make rest request from "gateway" to "internal" with url `http://internal:8082/some/rest`. Schema of request is browser->ingress->gateway->internal. Status of "internal" pod is `Running`.

Comment: when you say "http://internal:8082/some/rest", with "internal" you mean  the ip address of the service?

Comment: @suren No i mean dns name 'internal'. Service has name 'internal' and kubernetes create dns name for this service, so it is availabe inside cluster by name 'internal'. This works and was tested in other google project.(Only difference with current that it is exposed with LoadBalancer. Gateway service type is LoadBalancer in this project.)

Comment: can you share the yaml files of the deployments as well? I'd like to reproduce this use case.

Comment: @suren problem was solved, my gateway based on spring-cloud-gateway and i think issue was related to https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/205. For some reasons with LoadBalancer it works fine, but with Ingress - not. Thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in gateway application and Ingress combination, i upgraged gateway application version and it started to work