# Kubernetes Ingress Error: The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

In our GKE we have one service called `php-services`. It is defined like so:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: php-services
  labels:
    name: php-services
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    name: php-services
```

I can access this service from inside the cluster. If I run these commands on one of our pods (in `Default` namespace), I get expected results:

```
bash-4.4$ nslookup 'php-services'
   Name:      php-services
   Address 1: 10.15.250.136 php-services.default.svc.cluster.local
```

and

```
bash-4.4$ wget -q -O- 'php-services/health'
   {"status":"ok"}
```

So the service is ready and responding correctly. I need to expose this service to foreign traffic. I'm trying to do it with Ingress with following config:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-tls
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "kubernetes-ingress"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
    external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: "gke-ingress.goout.net"
  namespace: default
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
     - php.service.goout.net
    secretName: router-tls
  rules:
  - host: php.service.goout.net
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: php-services
          servicePort: 80
        path: /*
```

But then accessing http://php.service.goout.net/health gives an 502 error:

> Error: Server Error The server encountered a temporary error and could
>   not complete your request.
>   Please try again in 30 seconds.

We also have other services with the same config which run ok and are accessible form outside.

I've found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49076629/ingress-backend-rest-error-the-server-encountered-a-temporary-error-and-could-n) but that doesn't bring any sufficient answer either.
I've been also following the [Debug Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/) article but that also didn't help as the service itself is OK.

Any help with this issue highly appreciated.

Comment: what about https ://php.service.goout.net/health ?

Comment: @KonstantinVustin Nothing changes. Still the same error. (You can see for yourself, the url is public)

Comment: actually, i can see 404 now. Your route is handled by the default backend

Comment: @KonstantinVustin Yeah, we've just fixed the error. I'll soon post an answer here explaining what was wrong.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### EDIT TLDR

GKE Loadbalancer [only accepts HTTP status 200](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-check-concepts) while Kubernetes health checks accept [any code greater than or equal to 200 and less than 400](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/).

### Orignal answer

Ok, so we've figured out what was wrong.

Take a look at `yaml` definition of the deployment for the `php-services` service: (shortened)

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: php-services
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: php-services
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: php-services
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: php-services
          image: IMAGE_TAG
          livenessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              path: /health
              port: 80
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 60
            periodSeconds: 60
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 10
          readinessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              path: /health
              port: 80
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 60
            periodSeconds: 60
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 10
          ports:
          - containerPort: 80
```

The Apache server inside the image was configured in a way that it redirected from paths without trailing slash to paths with it. So when you requested `/health` you actually got HTTP status 301 pointing to `/health/` which then responded with 200.

In the scope of Kubernetes health checks this is OK as "[Any code greater than or equal to 200 and less than 400 indicates success.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/)"

However, the problem lied in the GKE Loadbalancer. It also has it's own GKE healthchecks derived from the checks in Deployment definition. The important difference is that [it only accepts HTTP status 200](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-check-concepts). And if the loadbalancer doesn't find a backend service healthy it won't pass any foreign traffic to it.

Therefore we had two options to fix this:

- Make the server inside the container respond with HTTPS status 200 to both
  `/health` and `/health/` (or more precisely just to `/health`)
- or change the `readinessProbe` and `livenessProbe` path definition to `/health/`.

We choose the later and it fixed the problem.